# issue while creating dynamic objects

Tags: angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, ng2-charts

I trying to create a dashboard which will display a chart`(ng2-charts)` with `Open, In Progress & closed` issues.

I'm getting data from making a service call. Below is my code.

From the response, I'm splitting the `Open, In Progress & closed` issues and pushing it `openIssue = [], inProgressIssue = [], closedIssue = []` respectively.

```
subscribe((response) => {
      // get open completed and In progress issues
      const issuesNotCompletedInCurrentSprint = response.contents.issuesNotCompletedInCurrentSprint;
      const completedIssues = response.contents.completedIssues.length;
      const openIssue = [];
      const inProgressIssue = [];
      const closedIssue = [];

      // Filtering closed issues
      this.closedIssue.push(completedIssues);

      // filter out open/inProgress issue from responce
      issuesNotCompletedInCurrentSprint.filter((item) => {
        if (item.statusId === '1') {
          openIssue.push(item);
        } else if (item.statusId === '3') {
          inProgressIssue.push(item);
        }
      });

      // Conunt issues
      this.totalOpenIssue.push(openIssue.length);
      this.totalInprogressIssue.push(inProgressIssue.length);
```

My issue is, Based on the above output ,I need to create the chartData which look like this.

```
barChartData:any[] = [
    {data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40], label: 'Open'},
    {data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90], label: 'In Progress'},
    {data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90], label: 'Closed'}
  ];
```

I tried this, but it draws the chart with wrong data. Not sure what is wrong here also please help me with the best practice.

```
      [
        { data: this.totalOpenIssue, label: 'Open' },
        { data: this.totalInprogressIssue, label: 'InProgress' },
        { data: this.closedIssue, label: 'Completed' }
      ]
```

Comment: What is `lineData`? What data is wrong?

Comment: lineData is closedIssue. I've updated my code